# Qt: Hide folders in getSaveFileName

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qfiledialog, qtwidgets

I would like to save a file using `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` without allowing to choose the path or at least hide folders.
Reading the doc I tried to set `QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly` as an option like this:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                tr("..."), path, tr("... (*.txt)"), 0, QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
```

but it's not working or it's not what I want.

Is there a way to save a file without being able to seek a location in the system and using `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` please? Or do I need to build my own QFileDialog where I will just write the name of the file?

I hope someone will understand my problem.

Comment: Why do you need file dialog for this if you only prefer the user to select a file name? I would not use QFileDialog for that personally, but just a custom input box.

Comment: This is what I have done so far but I would like something aesthetic. And implement this using `getSaveFileName` will ask before erase a file having the same name.

Comment: You can do that with an input and message box. It does not seem you would like to have a QFileDialog. You seem that you would like to have a custom input box.

Comment: Yes this is what I am finally doing. I just thought I could avoid this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep, understood. By the way, consider QML for the future. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comment, you are looking for a bit specific behavior which is not quite a QFileDialog, albeit somewhat similar, admittedly.

I believe it is not possible to shrink this feature down from QFileDialog, so I would personally go for implementing my own input box with the required sanity check in the background.

The QFileDialog implementation might give some hint for such checks, but it is not vital to see the source code of it as these are relatively simple operations.

You could then provide warning and error messages with message box. That being said, it might be more beneficial for Qt 5 to consider QML for such operations.

Comment: How would QML help here and not look “foreign” in a widgets application? I’d also point to QFileSystemModel, as it could be used for the custom selection dialog. (which would also be my suggestion)

Comment: @Frank: 1) I do not see widgets mentioned in the question other than QFileDialog. 2) Even if it was, putting this together in qml is simpler IMHO. 3) QML != !widgets; qml is just a language. Some people confuse it with QtQuick(Controls) though. It is possible to write widget based applications in QML. 4) QFSM is just a model, and not a view. 5) I am not sure you would need that here for this simple case. It is a bit too heavy IMHO.

Comment: QListView + QFSM, how can it be easier than that? Ok, at least until you need proxy models ;). For a single folder, just QDir plus list view is probably easier indeed if one isn’t familiar with model/view. And yes, I know that QML != QtQuick and that it is conceptually possible to combine QML + widgets, it’s just that there’s no built-in support for that in Qt, so it’s rather unlikely that user2886875 is going that route.

Comment: With "conceptually possible" I'm referring to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqpJEj15t9Q , btw.

Comment: @Frank: it is easier to have a line input and run the validation on "OK", and for that matter QML and QtQuick(Controls) are future proof; qtwidgets is not.